# Zone Gradient Fill on top of the Line chart instead of Below

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to make the Gradient appear on the opposite side of the line of a Highstock area chart.

Looking at the example at the Highstock chart example [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/intraday-breaks), the gradient fill color appears below the line:

[image]

I have tried searching around but was unable to succeed in figuring out how to achieve this effect. I tried with an `inverted` property, but I don't want the chart to be inverted, just the `fillColor` + I did some fiddling with the `linearGradient` attributes without any success. I've seen this achieved in other places:

[image]

I am using zones as well, and it only has to be for one particular zone:

```
zones: [
  {
    value: firstDatasetValue,
    color: '#ff6968',
    fillColor: {
      linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
      stops: [
        [0, "rgba(255, 105, 104, 0)"],
        [1, "rgba(255, 105, 104, 0.3)"],
      ],
    },
    threshold: Infinity,
  },
  {
    color: '#94caae',
    fillColor: {
      linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
      stops: [
        [0, "rgba(34, 197, 94, 0.3)"],
        [1, "rgba(34, 197, 94, 0)"],
      ],
    },
    threshold: 0
  }
]
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9x3L1uyo/

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect? :)

Comment: Can you fill the background with the gradient and fill the graph with white?

Comment: @enhzflep I might be able to, but the problem is I'm using zones and when the zone is above x amount it will be gradient green below the line, and when it is below x amount I want it to be red gradient above the line :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by setting `threshold` to `Infinity`, at the`series` and `navigator.series` as well. Then reverse the colors in `fillColor.stops`

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ocngftdr/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.area.threshold

--

**EDIT:**
In the case of zones, set `series.threshold` as the same value as `series.zones`

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5wtapy4f/

Comment: This seems to work by just putting infinity in the series in the sample you provided, however, in my own project, I use zones, and that seems to not work by putting in the threshold into the zone. I have updated my question :) anything above the first dataset should be a green gradient below. Anything that has a lesser value than the first dataset value should be red with the gradient on top :) I have included a fiddle where you can see the outcome